# How to display multiple fields in jComboBox but only insert one field in the database?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a table called Client that has clientID and clientName as fields, I would like to show the two fields in the combobox but I only want to insert the clientID in my other table after clicking the add button.

I have this method to fill my combobox

```
private void fillClient(){
Connection con = getConnection();
String sql = "Select clientID, clientfname from client";

    try {
        pst=con.prepareStatement(sql);
        optset = pst.executeQuery();
        while (optset.next()){
            String id = optset.getString("clientID");
            String nme = optset.getString("clientfname");
            String cmb = (id+"-"+nme);
            clientCmb.addItem(cmb);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }}
```

The problem is, the inserted data is the combined string.

Here's how I insert the selected item into the database.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        Connection con = getConnection();
        String client = (String) clientCmb.getSelectedItem();
  String driver = (String) driverCmb.getSelectedItem();
  String van = (String) vanCmb.getSelectedItem();

  String sql = "Insert into reservation (clientID,van,driverID) values('"+client+"','"+driver+"','"+van+"')";

  try {
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model class that represents your client and override `toString`:

```
public class Client {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    // Getters and setters

    public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

The text in combo box items will be displayed according to `toString` method. Set this model class as a type parameter for your `JComboBox`.

```
JComboBox<Client> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
```

Upon selection of combo box item, you can now obtain whole object. Do whatever you want with that object. Obtain id, name or whatever.

P.S. If all that code is generated by NetBeans GUI builder, my condolences.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to split the resulting string and fetch the first value.

```
String[] parts = string.split("-");
String id = parts[0];
```

edit: Branislav's answer is way better.

Answer (score 1):

After `String client = (String) clientCmb.getSelectedItem();`
do this

```
    String[] clientDetails = client.split("-");
    String clientID = clientDetails[0];
    String driver = (String) driverCmb.getSelectedItem();
  String van = (String) vanCmb.getSelectedItem();

  String sql = "Insert into reservation (clientID,van,driverID) values('"+clientID+"','"+driver+"','"+van+"')";

  try {
           Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
           stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Saved");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Reservation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }



    }
```